# Operating on large amounts of data on CPU/GPU

Tags: performance, parallel-processing, gpu, cpu, gpgpu

Well, I have  a simple app: I can load a picture, scale it with bicubic filtering, and get the average greyscale copy of it. They can be saved to a .BMP image then or processed as vertex attributes later on.

The main problem is the amount of data I have to work with, and the complexity of the functions operating on the data arrays.

Lets say I have a picture with size of 256*256. To scale it to 2048*2048 with bicubic interpolation, it takes 152 seconds. The problem is not saving the data to a file, because it takes less than a second. The interpolating function pretty complex to run through the dataset fast.
This data set is not necessarily a picture.

So, I want to **operate on large amounts of data** fast, but doing it **on CPU is pretty slow**. (Saying I want to work on a `20 000 * 20 000` picture, the 'simple' bicubic interpolation may take hours, and I haven't tested normal map generation yet).

I've Googled, and I've found OpenCL (I'm using OpenGL now, but I think it's very different). So as I understand I can **move the calculations to the GPU** with it. I've also read OpenCV is a pretty fast image processing lib.

Staying at GPU, it can process vertices, fragments, but for a `20k * 20k` image there's no such a resolution. As I know most GPUs support a max resolution of `4k*4k`, but maybe thats wrong. How can it work on larger sets than the max resolution (maybe my logic is wrong, but if I save the calculated data (with fragment shader) to a texture to read it back on CPU, it can't have any resolution).

*Is GPGPU similar to transform feedback, and is it even faster (if so then why) than CPU processing? Has GPU processing disadvantages to CPU processing? And what kind of tasks, calculations should I use GPUs for, I mean when is it faster to use GPU than CPU?*

**EDIT:** one idea came to my mind according to my last question in this post: if there's much `if(statement)`-s in my algorithm, is it a good idea to move it to GPU? This is one example, maybe there are more. I have an ATI card, and I have to write my own functions for these filterings.

Comment: 152s for a 256² to 2048² bicubic interpolation sounds like an awfully inefficient implementation. Just saying. Also scaling a picture is a problem that's easily split up into tiles. You don't have to process the whole picture at once, you can split it up into smaller tiles. For bicubic interpolation to work the possible smallest tile in the original picture would be a 4×4 tile.

Comment: yeah, that's another problem. I'm using it the same as in my shaders. 16 'texture' samples around a point, and interpolation in 'rows', then in 'coloumns'. In this app I use a function to get the pixel data from the 1 dim. array, and the interpolation works the same way.

Comment: You can also consider CUDA library if you are running on nVidia.

Comment: I have an ATI, but also I'd like to make it with OpenC_ if I switch to GPGPU.

Comment: OpenGL is for accessing your GPU's render pipeline. You are looking for OpenCL which allows you to run (almost) general purpose programs on your GPU.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have to implement it yourself, one thing to look out for is padding and correct boundary treatment. Other than that, it should be a fairly simple implementation, where one thread group can do one tile of the image.

You said that you have an AMD device, so you want to look at [AMD's OpenCL introduction](http://developer.amd.com/tools-and-sdks/heterogeneous-computing/amd-accelerated-parallel-processing-app-sdk/introductory-tutorial-to-opencl/).

If you can use libaries and you have a CUDA-enabled device, you can simply use [NPP](https://developer.nvidia.com/npp)'s `nppiResize` function. It has two versions, one for one channel and one for four channels (there are functions to convert three channel to four channel images, if you need it). However, it only supports 8-bits per channel. You can find it in the [NPP documentation](https://developer.nvidia.com/sites/default/files/akamai/cuda/files/CUDADownloads/NPP_Library.pdf).

The declaration is: `NppStatus nppiResize_8u_C1R (const Npp8u pSrc, NppiSize oSrcSize, int nSrcStep, NppiRect
oSrcROI, Npp8u pDst, int nDstStep, NppiSize dstROISize, double xFactor, double yFactor, int
eInterpolation)`

You can set the value for `eInterpolation` to `NPPI_INTER_CUBIC`. Other possible values are in the `NppiInterpolationMode` enum.

Comment: NPP looks fine, but I have ATI card, and I like to use ATI products. Also I forgot to write but I have to implement filtering functions myself. I will take a look at the declarations. +1

Comment: Woops. I must have misread that one. It can't be too hard either way. Good luck!

Comment: hmm. moving the filtering code with tiles to different threads is a great idea for such big images!

Comment: You want one thread group to work on one tile to increase data locality within your group.

Comment: Make sure to use pen&paper to draw the outline of your indexing scheme. Pictures say more than a thousand words ;)

Comment: thats common for me, I write down things or make a skretch before doing some code.;P